# Reducing the execution time in following program

Tags: c++, optimization, time-complexity

I need to optimize my answer for the following question without exceeding time limit ([0.5s](https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/pMvymcahZ8dY4g75q)). This isn't a homework or a competition or my interview question. I'm currently learning programming by my self **for fun** and I found this online.

*Given an array a that contains only numbers in the range from 1 to a.length, find the first duplicate number for which the second occurrence has the minimal index. In other words, if there are more than 1 duplicated numbers, return the number for which the second occurrence has a smaller index than the second occurrence of the other number does. If there are no such elements, return -1.*

This is my answer:

```
int firstDuplicate(std::vector<int> a) 
{
    int arrLen = a.size();
    int dupIndex = -1;
    int seen[arrLen];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
        seen[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen && dupIndex == -1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrLen && dupIndex == -1 && seen[j] != 0; j++)
            if (a[i] == seen[j])
                dupIndex = seen[j];
        seen[i] = a[i];
    }

    return dupIndex;
}
```

**[input]** `array.integer a`
**Guaranteed constraints:**

```
1 ≤ a.length ≤ 105,
1 ≤ a[i] ≤ a.length
```

How should I optimize my code and what are the factors on program optimization? (yes I'm a newbie into programming)

Comment: Hint: your algorithm is O(N * N). You can do this in O(N).

Comment: To explain what @Bathsheba means - at worst, you currently iterate over the whole array once for every element in the array.  You can change this so that, at worst, you only go over the array once.  SO users tend not to like giving answers to competitions / homework directly since it defeats the point of them....

Comment: @UKMonkey: Plus writing out the O(N) solution to this one is damn fiddly.

Comment: Smells like "do your own homework"...

Comment: You can find some motivation here: https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/find-duplicates-in-an-given-array-in-on-time-and-o1-extra-space/. They just find duplicates, not their indexes, so you have still some work to do.

Comment: @Bathsheba but aren't the fiddly ones the most fun? ;)

Comment: @OP Once you have a doubly-nested loop that goes over the array, you're doomed.  Trying to limit the loop with extra tests in the loop declaration is fools gold.  If you had 1,000 elements, that is 1,000,000 iterations you could be looking at.  Make that 100,000 elements, that means 10,000,000,000 iterations.  See how the number of iterations balloons to an extraordinary amount?

Comment: @Bathsheba: OTOH, O(N log N) isn't too hard. Create a copy of the input, but pair each element with its original index. Sort the input by value first, and original index second. (O log N). Duplicates are trivial to spot - they're now adjacent, and the first duplicate is always the second occurrence. This makes it an easy O(N) scan after sorting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First (naive) optimization: start the inner loop at `i+1`.

Second (also naive, since it uses quite a lot of memory) optimization: Allocate an array of length `a.length`, initialize to `-1`. Then, iterate once through your data and as soon as a number is found, store its index. If an index has been found already, you can detect that by checking against `-1`, and you have your duplicate.

Comment: There exists O(n) algorithm with O(1) additional memory for these input data. Just it modifies the input array and we don't know whether it is allowed. But it seems so since input vector is passed by value to the function. (Not my downvote, by the way. Don't know why someone downvoted without comment.)

Comment: Sure that exists. But it's not trivial to write down. My intention was not to give the optimal answer, just pointers on what easy measures the poster could do to improve his run time. I don't mind the downvotes, but if the reason is that I didn't give the optimal algorithm, I strongly disagree with the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

No need for additional answers. I figured it out.

```
int firstDuplicate(std::vector<int> a) 
{
    int arrLen = a.size();
    int dupIndex = -1;
    int seen[arrLen];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
        seen[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen && dupIndex == -1; i++)
    {
        if (seen[a[i]] == a[i] * -1)
            dupIndex = a[i];
        else
            seen[a[i]] = a[i] * -1;
    }

    return dupIndex;
}
```